# modal dialog jquery rules

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Dear all

I'm a newbie in PHP, jQuery and bad in English.

I want to ask about jQuery modal dialog rules, from database. This is my database:

[Database picture](http://i1230.photobucket.com/albums/ee498/aboxloserkidz/db.jpg)

This is my code: Javascript rules and jQuery Validate without the load of the database:

```
rules: {
  user: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    range: [1, 8]
  }                        
},
messages: {
user: {
required: "* sorry field user empty.",
number: "* Field user must number.",
    range: "* Field user must between 1 to 8"
}                     
}
```

I used PHP and this is my form field, from the user only.

```
<?php $user = array(
          'name'           => 'user',
          'id'             => 'user',
          'class'          => 'user',
          'value'          => '',
          'style'          => 'border: groove 2px;',
          'size'           => '3',
          'maxlength'      => '3'
          ); ?>
          <td> <?php echo form_label('User');?> </td>
        <td> : </td>
        <td> <?php echo form_input($user); ?></td>
```

The question is how to input rules with load a database.

For example:

If I login with userdata and load the database the `$items` value is `8`.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('items')
```

Are the range rules automatically between 1 to 8? Like the following image:

[My modal dialog](http://i1230.photobucket.com/albums/ee498/aboxloserkidz/bertanya.jpg)

And, if the login userdata to load database `$items` value is `6`, are the range rules automatically between `1` to `6`? The same question if `$items` is `4`.

I need your help.

Thank you so much for your attention.

Best regards,

Puja

Comment: jQueryUI dialog doesn't have `rules` / `messages` options, but jQuery Validate does... Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: oh yes,  jquery validate. thanks, i will edit my post. @AndrewWhitaker

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what form_input() does but you can try adding variable to input and extract it when attaching validation rules

```
$user = array(
      'name'           => 'user',
      'id'             => 'user',
      'class'          => 'user',
      'value'          => '',
      'style'          => 'border: groove 2px;',
      'size'           => '3',
      'maxlength'      => '3',
      'data-range'     => $this->session->userdata('items')
      );
```

And in javascript code

```
rules: {
  user: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      range: [1, parseInt($('#user').data('range'))]
}...
```

If data will not be added to the generated input field you can try add this to class, for example

```
 'class'          => 'user range_'.$this->session->userdata('items'),
```

and in js change

```
parseInt($('#user').attr('class'))
```

to

```
parseInt($('#user').attr('class').substring($('#user').attr('class').indexOf('range_')+6));   //add 6 as this is the length of range_
```